# How to define the policy in the case of continuous action space that sum up to 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on a continuous state-action space problem using policy gradient methods.

The environment action space is defined as ratios that has to sum up to 1 at each timestep. Hence, using the gaussian policy doesn't seem to be suitable in this case.

What I did instead is I tried to tweak the softmax policy (to make sure the policy network output sums up to 1), but I had hard time determining the loss function to use and eventually its gradient in order to update the network parameters.

So far, I have tried a discounted return-weighted Mean Squared Error, but the results aren't satisfactory.

Are there any other policies that can be used in this particular case? Or ar there any ideas which loss function to use?

Here is the implementation of my policy network (inside my agent class) in tensorflow.

```py
def policy_network(self):
        self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=[None, self.input_dims],
                                    name='input')
        self.label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.n_actions], name='label')
        # discounted return
        self.G = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[
            None,
        ], name='G')

        with tf.variable_scope('layers'):
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(
                inputs=self.input,
                units=self.l1_size,
                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            l2 = tf.layers.dense(
                inputs=l1,
                units=self.l2_size,
                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            l3 = tf.layers.dense(
                inputs=l2,
                units=self.n_actions,
                activation=None,
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

            self.actions = tf.nn.softmax(l3, name='actions')

        with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
            base_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.actions - self.label))
            loss = base_loss * self.G

        with tf.variable_scope('train'):
            self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head, you may want to try 2D-Gaussian or multivariate Gaussian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

For example, you could predict the 4 parameters (x_0, x_1, sigma_0, sigma_1) of 2D-Gaussian, which you could generate a pair of numbers on the 2D-Gaussian plane, say (2, 1.5), then you could use softmax to produce the desired action `softmax([2, 1.5])=[0.62245933 0.37754067]`.

Then you could calculate the probability of the pair of numbers on the 2D-Gaussian plane, which you could then use to calculate the negative log probability, advantage, etc, to make the loss function and update the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Dirichlet distribution? Your network can output concentration parameters `alpha > 0` and then you can use them to generate a sample which would sum to one. Both `PyTorch` and `TF` support this distribution and you can both sample and get `logProb` from them. In this case, in addition to getting your sample, since it is a probability distribution, you can get a sense its variance too which can be a measure of the agent confidence. For the action of 3 dimensions, having `alpha={1,1,1}` basically means your agent doesn't have any preference and having `alpha={100,1,1}` would imply that it is very certain about most of the weight should go to the first dimensions.

---

Edit based on the comment:

Vanilla REINFORCE would have a hard time optimizing the policy when you use Dirichlet distribution. The problem is, in vanilla policy gradient, you can control how fast you change your policy in the network parameters space through gradient clipping and adaptive learning rate, etc. However, what matters the most is to control the rate of change in the probability space. Some network parameters may change probabilities a lot more than the others. Therefore, even though you control the learning rate to limit the delta of your network parameters, you may change the variance of your Dirichlet distribution a lot, which makes sense for your network if you think. In order to maximize the log-prob of your actions, your network might focus more on reducing the variance than shifting the mode of your distribution which would later hurt you in both exploration and learning meaningful policy. One way to alleviate this problem is to limit the rate of change of your policy probability distribution through limiting the KL-divergence of your new policy ditribution vs old one. TRPO or PPO are two of the ways to address this issue and solve the constraint optimization problems.

It is also probably good to make sure that in practice `alpha > 1`. You can achieve this easily by using softplus `ln(1+exp(x)) + 1` on your neural network outputs before feeding it into your Drichlet distribution. Also monitor the gradients reaching your layers and make sure it exists.

You may also want to add the entropy of the distribution to your objective function to ensure enough exploration and prevent distribution with very low variance (very high alphas).

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have implemented your approach, but the agent does not seem to learn anything. In fact, the learning curves are pretty terrible. I was wondering whether or not their are some methods to debug REINFORCE?